# Setting Imageview size for icons in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android.In my app I am using an image view for action bar icon whose layouts are wrap content.Also I have all resp size images for each DPI's.But when I test it, the image looks too small in bigger size phone. I have also tried giving size to image view, but still it looks big in some phones while small in other. What I am missing in XML settings?

Comment: refer this link https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: srry, but not helpful.can u tell me what size shud i give which will make it look gud in all devices or shud i use weights

Comment: Select Action bar & tab icons -> insert your image you will get all the drawable folders

Comment: ok thnx and what about images outside action bar

Answer (score 0):

Use [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) to create different drawable directories depending on device size.

```
res/drawable/your_image.png              // drawable for normal screen size ("default")
res/drawable-small/your_image.png        // drawable for small screen size
res/drawable-large/your_image.png        // drawable for large screen size
res/drawable-xlarge/your_image.png       // drawable for extra-large screen size
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have different pictures with different resolutions, and you want to resize the ImageView according to screen size, you should place the ImageViews inside a Layout and assign weight to them. They will occupy the space according to the weight you assigned, regardless of screen size.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:weightSum = "2"
        android:orientation = "horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight = "1" />
        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight = "1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Just for an idea, this code will split two ImageViews equally horizontally regardless of screen size.

Comment: thnx it solves problem for width but what about height?

Comment: For height you can assign weight to the LinearLayout itself. Lets say your root parent layout has `weightSum = "100"` and orientation is vertical, and you want to give your child layout 25% of screen size , you can assign weight `layout_weight="25"` to your inner linear layout in which your ImageViews reside. And give `layout_height="match_parent"` to ImageViews.